# Passing select parameter along with the form data in html

Tags: html, forms, select, post

I have a sample feedback web page which displays div blocks with the input fields, corresponding to the department chosen using select element using some javascript logic and the source code is below

```
<html>

<body onload="deptSelector();"> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        document.getElementById("ece").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("it").style.display = "none";
    }

    function deptSelector() {
        var val = document.getElementById("department").value;
        if(val == "Ece") {
            document.getElementById("ece").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("it").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ece").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("it").style.display = "block";      
        }   
    }
</script>

    <div>
        <label> Department:</label>
        <select id="department" name="dept" onchange="deptSelector()">          
            <option value="Ece">Ece</option>
            <option value="IT">It</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

    <div id="ece">
        <form id="eceFbForm" action="test.jsp" method="POST">
            <label> Enter the feedback for the following ECE staffs</label>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Ece_staff_1:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="eceSt1">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Ece_staff_2:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="eceSt2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">        
        </form>     
    </div>

    <div id="it">
        <form id="itFbForm" action="test.jsp" method="POST">
            <label> Enter the feedback for the following IT staffs</label>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>It_staff_1:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="itSt1">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>It_staff_2:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="itSt2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">        
        </form>     
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently i am not able to pass the select option parameter in the post data because the forms are in separate div blocks. So how do i re-alter the forms so that i get the select option parameter along with only the options input by the user corresponding to the div block?

Comment: Handle `submit` event on `form`.

Comment: @abhitalks:  can u please explain it briefly?

Comment: as I understand your select options re out of the froms. and on form post you do not receive selected values in these selection options. if that is the case you need to add some hidden fields in forms and on selection changed of the select option set selected value/text in those hidden fields and get hiddend filed values in the form post

Comment: @aarish: Added the explanation as an answer.

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah: Like u said i added the hidden field in each of the div blocks <input type="hidden" id="deptOption">. Then using js, i try to set the value using document.getElementById("deptOption").value = val;. But i get the parameter 'deptOption' to be empty in the post data. Can't understand what the reason is?

Comment: @abhitalks: Thanks a lot.. the answer was well-instructed!

Comment: @abhitalks: The first method u suggested appends the param to the url as a get request but i want it to be post data of the url. Second method does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing much in your current markup, you could do it in two ways.

**(1)** Handle the form submit event and add the `select` value as a querystring.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/KsGHS/1/***

*Relevant HTML*:

```
<form id="..." ... onsubmit="chk(this);">
```

*Relevant Javascript*:

```
function chk(frm) {
    var opt = document.getElementById("department").value;
    frm.action = frm.action + "&dept=" + opt;
    frm.submit;
}
```

**(2)** Add two hidden inputs to each of your forms and then handle the form submit to insert the `select` value.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/f99BB/1/***

*Relevant HTML*:

```
<form id="eceFbForm" ... onsubmit="chk(this);">
<input name="dept" type="hidden" />
...
<form id="itFbForm" ... onsubmit="chk(this);">
<input name="dept" type="hidden" />
```

*Relevant Javascript*:

```
function chk(frm) {
    var opt = document.getElementById("department").value;
    frm.dept.value = opt;
    frm.submit;
}
```

*Note*: As a best practice, event handlers must be attached unobtrusively. The above code is for illustration only.